# How to access component property in Ember.computed.sort

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember 1.13 I have a component that uses Ember.computed.sort:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    sortedItems: Ember.computed.sort("allItems", function(a, b) {
        //How to access columnList from here?
    }
    columnList: ["name","shortcode"]
})
```

I need to access columnList property of the component to customize the behaviour of comparison function provided to Ember.computed.sort. How to access the columnList inside comparison function in a place indicated in the code above?

Comment: `columnList` property is inside your `component` or `controller` ?

Comment: @rinoldsimonI do believe it is under `component` it is stated above 

`export default Ember.Component.extend({
    columnList: ["name","shortcode"]
})`

Comment: @Mikelemuel does the below solution works ?

Comment: @rinoldsimon i can confirm , column list is a property inside a component

Comment: @Mikelemuel I have updated the answer with a twiddle example. Please verify the answer if you find it helpful. Thanks

Comment: @rinoldsimon thanks, what version of Ember is your twiddle use?

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski `3.4.3`, since I couldn't able to run ember 1.13 in twiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `cloumnList` property is under the same `component` where you use `Ember.computed.sort`, just use `this.get('columnList');` to access the `columnList` property

```
...
sortedItems: Ember.computed.sort("allItems", function(a, b) {
  this.get('columnList');
}),
...
```

[ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/66abde344d98d86cd84c61d6d3f5c4c0?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) example.

Comment: it does not work, this is something else than the component

Comment: this is not a component inside sort function. Here is a watch over this: https://pasteboard.co/I67ALEC.jpg

Comment: Is this an issue with your outdated ember version? In latest version it works as described in answer: https://ember-twiddle.com/692f836557dbca2fb50d99e36aa6fb6f